# Clear [rootParams] doesn't work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a tabs app with 3 tabs:

1. Home Page
2. Find Page
3. Chats Page

I need to display on the Home Page a tappable element that should open the Find Page and pass it a param called filterOnSport.

I came up with the combination of rootParams and Events publish/subscribe as a solution.

First I implemented a subscription on the "change-tab" event (I talked about the "clear-find-tab-params" later):

```
// Tabs controller
export class TabsPage {
      @ViewChild(Tabs) tabs: Tabs;

      tab1Root: any = HomePage;
      tab2Root: any = FindPage;
      tab3Root: any = ChatsPage;

      findTabParams: any = {};

    constructor(public events: Events) {
        events.subscribe('change-tab', (tab, filterOnSport) => {
          console.log('TabsPage#constructor - change-tab event received with params: ', tab, filterOnSport);
          if (filterOnSport) this.findTabParams.filterOnSport = filterOnSport;
          this.tabs.select(tab);
        });

        events.subscribe('clear-find-tab-params', _ => {
          console.log('TabsPage#constructor - clear-find-tab-params event received.');
          this.findTabParams = {};
        });
      }
    }
```

Then I pass the params to the Find Tab through the rootParams attribute:

```
<ion-tabs #tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [rootParams]="findTabParams" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="chatbubbles" [tabsHideOnSubPages]=true></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Then I trigger this from my Home Page via an action function :

```
onSuggestedEventClick(sport: string): void {
    this.events.publish('change-tab', 1, sport);
  }
```

And finally, consume the params in my Find Page controller :

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    // Check if page is open with a sport to filter on, within parameters
    // Otherwise, default sport filter to 'all'
    let filterParam = this.navParams.get('filterOnSport');
    console.log('filter ', filterParam);

    if (filterParam) {
      this.sportFilteredOn = filterParam;
      // Clear findTabParams so it is not used again when navigating normally
      this.eventsCtrl.publish('clear-find-tab-params');
    } else {
      this.sportFilteredOn = 'all';
    }

    // Trigger the refresh of the events list
    this.refreshEventsList();
  }
```

I publish a "clear-find-tab-params" to clear the rootParams because my Find Page can be accessed by naturally clicking the Find Tab. In this case I don't want to filter the results.

Based on this I have two questions :

1. Went I click on my Home Page I get redirected to the Find Tab and the results are correctly filtered. the clear event is well published and well received but the findTabParams doesn't seem to be cleared... because when I go back to my Find Tab when navigating normally (I mean clicking the tab) it finds the filterOnSport param and filters on it... How could I do?
2. Is there a whole other way but better one to do what I need?

**** EDIT FOR SOLUTION ****

I ended up modifying the clear-find-tab-params subscription to the following:

```
events.subscribe('clear-find-tab-params', _ => {
      console.log('TabsPage#constructor - clear-find-tab-params event received.');
      if (this.findTabParams.filterOnSport) this.findTabParams.filterOnSport = null;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to change the clear-find-tab-params subscription to the following:

```
events.subscribe('clear-find-tab-params', _ => {
      console.log('TabsPage#constructor - clear-find-tab-params event received.');
      if (this.findTabParams.filterOnSport) this.findTabParams.filterOnSport = null;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this and just used routes. I then used routerLink to navigate to the routes and pass any required parameters.

You can see the complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing (in the APM-Final folder).

Here are the routes:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductListComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':id/edit',
    component: ProductEditComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'info',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'info',
        component: ProductEditInfoComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tags',
        component: ProductEditTagsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
])
```

],

The "info" and "tags" are the two tabs.

Here is the code to navigate to the tabs:

```
    <div class="wizard">
        <a [routerLink]="['info']" routerLinkActive="active">
            Basic Information  <span [ngClass]="{'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign':
                                                  !isValid('info')}"></span>
        </a>
        <a [routerLink]="['tags']" routerLinkActive="active">
            Search Tags  <span  [ngClass]="{'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign':
                                                  !isValid('tags')}"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, but AFAIK Ionic uses a custom implementation of the Angular router, the [`NavController`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

Comment: Ah. I don't know ionic.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do that would be to publish the event from the `HomePage` (which is a child tab) and subscribe to that event in the `FindPage` but instead of using the rootParams, you can use the same event to send the data. Please take a look at this **[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S256P4OpjcHsBADJ3y1I)**

Like you can see there, we select the second tab directly from the child tab by doing `this.navCtrl.parent.select(1);`. Then we use a `setTimeout` to wait a few ms to give some time for that tab to be selected, and then we publish the event, sending some data:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class FirstTabPage {

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private eventsCtrl: Events) {}

  public selectSecondTab(): void {
      let searchParam = 'HelloWorld';

      // Select the second tab
      this.navCtrl.parent.select(1);

      setTimeout(() => {

        // Publish the event to show the parameter
        this.eventsCtrl.publish('searchParam', searchParam);

      }, 50);
  }
}
```

Then in the second tab, we subscribe to that event, we get the data from the event too, and then we use the `ionViewWillLeave` hook to clean the parameter when leaving the tab:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class SecondTabPage {

  public parameter: string;

  constructor(private eventsCtrl: Events) {
    this.eventsCtrl.subscribe('searchParam', (searchParam) => {
      this.parameter = searchParam;
    });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    // Clean the parameter so next time it will be empty
    this.parameter = null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, and the reason is that the first time you press that button from the first tab, chances are that the second tab has not been opened yet, so the page inside of that tab was not created yet. When you press the button and change the tab, here the tab is created, and after that **the page subscribe to the event that sends the parameter**. So the setTimeout only is used the first time you press the button, if the second tab has not been created yet.

Comment: Thanks. I finally managed to do it as I was trying at the beginning. Only thing I had to change was `this.findTabParams = {}` to if `(this.findTabParams.filterOnSport) this.findTabParams.filterOnSport = null`

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue :) Id you don't mind, add it as an answer and mark it as the accepted one, so other SO users facing the same issue could know how to fix it and we can close the question.

Comment: Sure @sebaferreras. Will do it as soon as I get the possibility to do it, in two days...